# Sample to replicate the ScrollViewer.LeftHeader and ScrollViewer.TopHeader features in Windows Store apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Is there any any msdn sample or model sample available over the net to get clear understanding about the ScrollViewer.TopHeader and ScrollViewer.LeftHeader. I want to freeze the First column and First row in my Grid view display. Is it possible to achieve using this feature ?
Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample here uses the header configurations: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-input-and-manipulation-44125241